# Will const pointer generate const field in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, iterator

## Part-1

The C++ `const` type is really confusing me. Here's my example in C++14:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <class K, class V> class MyNode {
public:
  std::pair<const K, V> value;
};

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyIterator {
public:
  MyIterator(NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ~MyIterator() = default;
  MyIterator(const MyIterator &) = default;
  MyIterator &operator=(const MyIterator &) = default;

  std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() { return node_->value; }
  const std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() const { return node_->value; }
  std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
  const std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() const { return &(node_->value); }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &operator++() { return *this; }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> operator++(int) { return *this; }

  bool operator==(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ == other.node_;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ != other.node_;
  }

private:
  NodePtr node_;
};

template <class K, class V> class MyHashMap {
public:
  using Iterator = MyIterator<K, V, MyNode<K, V> *>;
  using ConstIterator = MyIterator<K, V, const MyNode<K, V> *>;

  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator begin() const { return ConstIterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator cbegin() const { return ConstIterator(&node); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator end() const { return ConstIterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator cend() const { return ConstIterator(nullptr); }

  MyNode<K, V> node;
};

void test(const int &a) {}

int main(void) {
  MyHashMap<int, int> hm;
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.cbegin(); i != hm.cend();
       i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile by: `clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o main.exe`

Which give me:

```
main.cpp:53:43: error: no viable conversion from 'MyIterator<[2 * ...], MyNode<int, int> *>' to 'MyIterator<[2 * ...], const MyNode<int, int> *>'
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
                                          ^   ~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:11:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'MyHashMap<int, int>::Iterator' (aka 'MyIterator<int, int, MyNode<int, int> *>') to 'const MyNode<int, int> *' for 1st
      argument
  MyIterator(NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ^
main.cpp:13:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'MyHashMap<int, int>::Iterator' (aka 'MyIterator<int, int, MyNode<int, int> *>') to
      'const MyIterator<int, int, const MyNode<int, int> *> &' for 1st argument
  MyIterator(const MyIterator &) = default;
  ^
main.cpp:18:48: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'std::pair<const int, int> *' with an rvalue of type 'const std::pair<const int, int> *'
  std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:58:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'MyIterator<int, int, const MyNode<int, int> *>::operator->' requested here
    test(i->second);
          ^
2 errors generated.
```

## Part-2

Thanks to comments, I rewrite my hash map and iterator, but got a new problem. Here's the new example in C++14:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <class K, class V> class MyNode {
public:
  MyNode<K, V> *prev;
  MyNode<K, V> *next;
  std::pair<const K, V> value;
};

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyConstIterator;

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyIterator {
public:
  MyIterator(NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ~MyIterator() = default;
  MyIterator(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;
  MyIterator(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other)
      : node_(other.get()) {}
  MyIterator &operator=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;
  MyIterator &operator=(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    if (this == &other) {
      return *this;
    }
    node_ = other.node_;
    return *this;
  }

  NodePtr get() const { return node_; }

  std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() { return node_->value; }
  std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &operator++() {
    node_ = node_->next;
    return *this;
  }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> operator++(int) {
    MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> save = *this;
    node_ = node_->next;
    return save;
  }
  bool operator==(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ == other.node_;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ != other.node_;
  }

private:
  NodePtr node_;
};

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyConstIterator {
public:
  MyConstIterator(const NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ~MyConstIterator() = default;
  MyConstIterator(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other)
      : node_(other.get()) {}
  MyConstIterator(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;
  MyConstIterator &operator=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    if (this == &other) {
      return *this;
    }
    node_ = other.node_;
    return *this;
  }
  MyConstIterator &operator=(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;

  const NodePtr get() const { return node_; }

  const std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() { return node_->value; }
  const std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
  MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &operator++() {
    node_ = node_->next;
    return *this;
  }
  MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> operator++(int) {
    MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> save = *this;
    node_ = node_->next;
    return save;
  }
  bool operator==(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ == other.node_;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ != other.node_;
  }

private:
  const NodePtr node_;
};

template <class K, class V> class MyHashMap {
public:
  using Iterator = MyIterator<K, V, MyNode<K, V> *>;
  using ConstIterator = MyConstIterator<K, V, MyNode<K, V> *>;

  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator begin() const { return ConstIterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator cbegin() const { return ConstIterator((MyNode<K, V> *)&node); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator end() const { return ConstIterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator cend() const { return ConstIterator((MyNode<K, V> *)nullptr); }

  MyNode<K, V> node;
};

void test(const int &a) {}

int main(void) {
  MyHashMap<int, int> hm;
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.cbegin(); i != hm.cend();
       i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with: `clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o main.exe`, gives me:

```
main.cpp:79:11: error: cannot assign to non-static data member 'node_' with const-qualified type 'MyNode<int, int> *const'
    node_ = node_->next;
    ~~~~~ ^
main.cpp:112:75: note: in instantiation of member function 'MyConstIterator<int, int, MyNode<int, int> *>::operator++' requested here
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
                                                                          ^
main.cpp:90:17: note: non-static data member 'node_' declared const here
  const NodePtr node_;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

How could I implement the `operator++` in `MyConstIterator` ?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: The code you posted [compiles without errors](https://godbolt.org/z/oYezMw). You must instantiate the template somewhere in code you do not show (it also isnt in the github link, thats only the template also)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Hi, I updated the question with a minimum example.

Comment: thats a different error now. there is no conversion from `Iterator` to `ConstIterator`

Comment: oh thank you! I will add a constructor from Iterator to ConstIterator. And try again.

Comment: well, sorry, you shouldn't modify the question too frequently (and I shouldn't have tried to answer in a comment). Its in a much better shape than before, all the code and error message included, so the fixed code should now go to an answer

Comment: emmmm, no more modify

Comment: The fact that there's some relationship between types `T` and `U` doesn't automatically confer any relationship on `Template<T>` and `Template<U>`. Out of the box, `Template<SomeType*>` and `Template<const SomeType*>` are two distinct, unrelated classes. If there is to be some relationship between them, it's up to the author to implement it, e.g. by giving one a constructor that takes the other, or a conversion operator that returns the other.

Comment: In addition, your `ConstIterator::operator->` attempts to return a non-const pointer `std::pair<const int, int>*`, while holding a `const MyNode*` pointer. Everywhere you use `std::pair<const K, V>`, you'd need something like `decltype(node_->value)` instead. In fact, I don't think `MyIterator` even needs `K` and `V` template parameters; `NodePtr` carries all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, I come up with my solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <class K, class V> class MyNode {
public:
  MyNode<K, V> *prev;
  MyNode<K, V> *next;
  std::pair<const K, V> value;
};

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyConstIterator;

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyIterator {
public:
  MyIterator(NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ~MyIterator() = default;
  MyIterator(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;
  MyIterator(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other)
      : node_(other.get()) {}
  MyIterator &operator=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;
  MyIterator &operator=(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    if (this == &other) {
      return *this;
    }
    node_ = other.node_;
    return *this;
  }

  NodePtr get() const { return node_; }

  std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() { return node_->value; }
  std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &operator++() {
    node_ = node_->next;
    return *this;
  }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> operator++(int) {
    MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> save = *this;
    node_ = node_->next;
    return save;
  }
  bool operator==(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ == other.node_;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ != other.node_;
  }

private:
  NodePtr node_;
};

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyConstIterator {
public:
  MyConstIterator(const NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ~MyConstIterator() = default;
  MyConstIterator(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other)
      : node_(other.get()) {}
  MyConstIterator(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;
  MyConstIterator &operator=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    if (this == &other) {
      return *this;
    }
    node_ = other.node_;
    return *this;
  }
  MyConstIterator &operator=(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &) = default;

  const NodePtr get() const { return node_; }

  const std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() { return node_->value; }
  const std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
  MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &operator++() {
    node_ = node_->next;
    return *this;
  }
  MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> operator++(int) {
    MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> save = *this;
    node_ = node_->next;
    return save;
  }
  bool operator==(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ == other.node_;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyConstIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ != other.node_;
  }

private:
  NodePtr node_;
};

template <class K, class V> class MyHashMap {
public:
  using Iterator = MyIterator<K, V, MyNode<K, V> *>;
  using ConstIterator = MyConstIterator<K, V, MyNode<K, V> *>;

  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator begin() const { return ConstIterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator cbegin() const { return ConstIterator((MyNode<K, V> *)&node); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator end() const { return ConstIterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator cend() const { return ConstIterator((MyNode<K, V> *)nullptr); }

  MyNode<K, V> node;
};

void test(const int &a) {}

int main(void) {
  MyHashMap<int, int> hm;
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.cbegin(); i != hm.cend();
       i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  return 0;
}
```